# Don't log payload if error occurred in particular endpoint

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I am using NLog to log errors into a file when they occur and I also log the payload in the body request. But I don't want to log the payload if, for example, an error occurred while authenticating, because I have a username and password there.

What are your solutions for this issue?

I use a generic class to handle my HttpClient requests.

```
private static async Task<ApiMethodResult<string>> SendGenericRequestAsync(this HttpClient client,
            HttpMethod method,
            string requestString, object payload = null)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(ConnectionUrl.ExternalUrl + requestString),
                Method = method
            };

            if (payload != null && method != HttpMethod.Get)
            {
                HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json");
                requestMessage.Content = requestContent;
            }

            ApiMethodResult<string> result = new ApiMethodResult<string>();
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;

            try
            {
                responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                string errorMessage = $"Cannot connect to external data API. Requested url: {requestString}";
                result.SetErrorMessage(errorMessage);
                StaticLogger.LogError(errorMessage);

                return result;
            }

            string httpContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            result.ApiData = httpContent;
            return result;
        }
```

This is my nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="C:\Users\albug\source\repos\orgill-vendor-portal-v2\InnerLog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target name="default" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="LogFolderPath"
            layout="Logger: ${logger}${newline}
Date: ${shortdate}${newline}
Time: ${time}${newline}
LogType: ${level}${newline}
URL: ${aspnet-request-url:IncludeQueryString=true}${newline}
Payload: ${aspnet-request-posted-body}${newline}
Controller: ${aspnet-mvc-controller}${newline}
Endpoint: ${aspnet-mvc-action}${newline}
Message: ${message}${newline}"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="default" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem an issue. What about remove authentication info from the log?

Comment: How do you suggest doing that? All of my httpclient requests, alongside those from other controllers use this generic request. @LorenzoIsidori

Comment: are your authentication info in query string? or are them in headers param? If you know this, you know what to remove before logging

Comment: They are in the Request Payload as a JSON object 
{
    "username": "uName",
    "password": "pass"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a random search I actually found out that you can use a conditional operator-ish in the NLog layout.

What I did is this:

```
Payload: ${when:when='${aspnet-mvc-controller}'=='Account':inner=restricted:else=${aspnet-request-posted-body}}${newline}
```

So basically if the controller inside which the log action was triggered is "Account", it will put "restricted", else it will put the actual request body.

[Here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer) is the actual documentation.

```
${when:when=[condition to be verified]:inner=[what to log if true]:else=[what to print if not]}
```